# catoptions destroys french active characters ! and :

Tags: babel, characters, french

A user of my [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package reported, that there’s an issue with the activ characters in french, i.e. `!`, `;`, `?` and `:`. I found out that it’s not a bug in `menukeys` but [`catoptions`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/catoptions) seems to interferre with [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test:
    \item Test;
    \item Test?
    \item Test!
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives

[image: without catoptions]

without `catoptions`, but

[image: with catoptions]

with `catoptions`.

As you can see the `!` and the `:` seem to lose their activeness. So the question is: **How to restore the activeness of `!` and `:`?**

Comment: The doc of `catoptions` says "In fact, the package is meant to be loaded on top of other packages, so as to exploit its catcode preserving scheme". Does changing the package loading order help?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Loading `catoptions` before `babel` is even worse! For some reasons `frenchle` is loaded, and many unscrutable errors are raised.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: That’s what I tried first but as egreg said that makes every thing worse that better :-(

Comment: @Tobi A workaround is to say `\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandon{:}\shorthandon{!}}` in the preamble, but I don't know whether this has side effects with `menukeys`.

Comment: @egreg: This seems to work. Do you know why (or where) `catoptions` deactivates them?

Comment: @Tobi The package aims to be "catcode independent", but it outsmarts itself. It does `\AtBeginDocument{\cptrestorecatcodes}`, but this command doesn't take into account characters possibly activated by Babel. It's a clear bug.

Comment: Then @AhmedMusa may help an take a look at it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `microtype` package with the babel and kerning options fixes this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, kerning]{microtype}
\RequirePackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test:
    \item Test;
    \item Test?
    \item Test!
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It also fixes issues with packages such as `cleveref` and the like. I'm not exactly sure why; maybe someone more knowledgeable can comment.

Comment: I think `microtype` replaces `babel`'s active character scheme with its font kerning adjustment (as specified in `microtype.cfg`). That is, `microtype` hooks into `babel`s language switching mechanism to turn on extra kerning for these characters whenever the language is french. The characters are then never active.

Comment: Well, after all, one can prefer not to use `microtype`. Hence this answer, though useful, is more a workaround than a definitive solution, isn't it?

Comment: The definitive solution would be a bug fix in `catoptions` but we hav to wait for Ahmed. If you don’t like to use `microtype`, than the `\shorthandon` workaround mentioned by egreg should help.

Answer (score 4):

One of the aims of *catoptions* package is to provide normal (i.e., TeX's default) catcodes for programmers. The ‘prevailing’ catcodes (i.e., those in force before *catoptions* is loaded) are then restored for typesetting at `\AtBeginDocument` via

```
\AtBeginDocument{\cptrestorecatcodes}
```

But *babel* enforces active catcodes before or after `\cptrestorecatcodes`  is executed, depending on which of the packages (*babel* or *catoptions*) is loaded first.

The solution that works without defeating the original intention of *catotpions* package is the following:

```
\AtEndOfPackage{\BeforeStartOfDocument{\cptrestorecatcodes}}
```

I will update *catoptions* package accordingly.