# Tikz timing package error

Tags: errors, packages, tikz-timing

I try to use tikz timing package and with the Data description after compilation, i obtain this error : Package tikz Error: + or - expected. \end{frame}

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\geometry{paperwidth=150mm,paperheight=105mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=0.1,timing/xunit=0.5cm]        
    H & 22{2c} \\   
    $D$ & DD{a}DDD{b}DDD{c}\\
    $Q$ & \\
    \extracode
    \begin{background}[dotted,help lines]
        \vertlines{}
    \end{background}
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item La fonction logique s'exprime alors sous la forme de variables booléennes reliées entre elle par des fonctions de l'algèbre de Boole
\item La représentation sous forme de tableau ou de matrice est limitée à environ 5 variables.

\item $f(a)=\overline{a}$ Fonction NON
\item $f(a,b,c)=\overline{c}b+a\overline{b}$    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Problem is fix for the tikz timing package but new error :pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts. \end{frame}

Comment: The problem is the `french` option for Babel, that changes the way characters such as `-` are used. A workaround is `\usepackage[babel, kerning]{microtype}` _after_ `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146391/catoptions-destroys-french-active-characters-and.

Comment: @benoit The first hit on Google with the error message printed when compiling the new code gives a working answer. With this [edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/531446/revisions), this question has become a big mess. You're mixing two different problems in the same question.